# C++ in-place placement new

Tags: c++, placement-new

Basically, if I have a variable `T value`, and a function `T func(const T &)` that transforms a `T` into another, can I do `new (&value) T(func(value))`? I'm not sure if rewriting the same place can cause problem. Can the old `value` get overwritten before `func(value)` finishes?

**UPDATE:** I'm doing this to try to turn a tail-recursion into a loop (compilers can't optimize it due to non-trivial destructor). Methods better than placement new are more than welcome!

Comment: Why not simply `value = func(value);` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 `T` might not be copy (or move) assignable.

Comment: So you try to bypass `T` interface :/ ... Note also that you  forget to call `value` destructor with your placement new.

Comment: Yes... I'm trying to turn a recursion in to a loop, and I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: I think you need to post a separate question where you don't focus on `placement new` (or don't mention it at all). You need to show the (minimal) code you want to transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do that (safely). Placement new must be used on an allocated but uninitialized memory or on a POD object.

You can't just bypass constructors, copy, move ctors/assignments and destructors on objects (except for PODs). If you want to do that, there is something wrong on your design and you need to go to the drawing board.